# div with border over image and body background-color

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

i have an logo which i want centered in the header of my jq-mobile site, i want the rest of the image dynamic so i made an div which makes it complete. but i dont can get it over the image. if i set position absolute it wents away. i made an jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/nMR85/52/.

My div is

```
#example1 {
-moz-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
border-top-right-radius: 15px;
background-color: #fff;
height:3em;
}
```

And here is an image who i want it to look like http://www.imagebanana.com/view/f69uguue/final.png

How can it be done? My other problem is that i cant find the attribute to change the background color of the content to WHITE. The ThemeRoller from jqmobile.com is also not working. Which attribute it is?!
Thanks

Comment: Next time please leave unneccesary code out of jsfiddle. `.ui-bar-a` and `.ui-overlay-a` in your css do not apply to your html code.

Comment: .ui-bar-a does make changes to the blue background. and .ui-overlay-a should be the thing where i can change the background of the content

Comment: Sure. In your site maybe, but in fiddle both classes are not present in your html.

Comment: change the border to 2px solid of .ui-bar-a and see how it affects the fiddle!

Comment: f**k me. I totally missed jqmobile bit. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative margin-top on the #example1 style:

```
#example1 {
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    height:3em;
    margin-top:-2.8em;
}​
```

Here the result:
http://jsfiddle.net/nMR85/57/

The attribute to change the background color is `background-color`:

> background-color: white;

You can also use `background` which will overwrite any other background attribute in case there's some image.

Comment: thanks thanks thanks! working great. but not the background :/

Comment: You have to create another style for the content. For example `class="content"` and adding the class on the style sheet with the background attribute. Here you have it: http://jsfiddle.net/nMR85/64/

Answer (score 1):

hey for `background-color:white;` you can update your `jquery.mobile.min.css` with mentioned below **CSS** property

**CSS**

```
 .ui-mobile .ui-page-active {
    background:white;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
}
```